# Physics of Skiing: Ideal Carving Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry

I am conducting a research paper on the physics of skiing, specifically how ski parameters affect the ski's ideal carve. I have come across [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0310086) (abstract link to arXiv paper), which is incredibly relevant but I am having trouble deciphering its text. From the very start, chapter 2.1, they claim

> According to figure 1, an approximate formula for the smooth curve described by the edge of the ski is $y\approx x^2/(2R_{sc})-d$. This relation implies $d\approx C^2/(8R_{sc})$. Therefore, we approximately have
>   $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\approx\frac1R_{SC}$$

How did they arrive at these conclusions? What math is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Figure 1 from the linked document shows the overhead of a typical carving ski:
[image]

The length of the portion of the skis between the arrows is $C$, the depth of the curve below this horizontal line is $d$. The curve appears to follow a [parabola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) with a radius that is given by $R_{SC}$ (radius of the side-cut). Since the $y$ axis is zero along the line $C$, then the parabola can be expressed by their approximate relation,
$$y\approx\frac{x^2}{2R_{SC}} - d$$
To get the second relationship, set $y=0$ and $x=C/2$ (i.e., look at one of the arrows):
$$0\approx\frac{\frac14C^2}{2R_{SC}}-d\to d\approx\frac{C^2}{8R_{SC}}$$
This defines the depth of the curve in terms of the length of the side cut and its radius.

The last relationship is found simply by taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ twice:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}\approx\frac{2x}{2R_{SC}}=\frac{x}{R_{SC}} \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\approx\frac{1}{R_{SC}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but why did you divide the x^2 value by 2Rsc?

Comment: @user1750156: It's a scale factor. Since $1/R_{SC}$ is (presumably) less than 1, it widens the curve. If it were greater than 1, the curve would be more narrow.

Comment: Is it just arbitrary then?? you could just as easily chose 3 or 2.1?

Comment: I am not sure how you came to that conclusion, it is certainly *not* arbitrary. The side-cut has a known radius and the authors are fitting a parabola to it.

Comment: Why did they use 2Rsc, where is the two coming from?

Comment: My only suggestion is to work out the geometry yourself. You know the chord length, $C$, of a circle of radius $R_{SC}$ and that the general form of a parabola is $y=ax^2$. Work from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13690/discussion-between-user1750156-and-kyle-kanos)